# Remove consecutive duplicate words javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a problem to delelete duplicate words but consecutive ones.I have string from api like below;

```
var string='Girne Street No:1/2 Girne Girne KKTC KKTC'
```

I need as result

> Girne Street No:1/2 Girne KKTC

Thanks for helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex solution would be this:

```js
string = 'Girne Street No:1/2 Soğukçeşme Soğukçeşme Sokağı Sokağı'

result = string.replace(/([^\wÇçĞğİıÖöŞşÜü]|^)([\wÇçĞğİıÖöŞşÜü]+)(?=[^\wÇçĞğİıÖöŞşÜü]+\2([^\wÇçĞğİıÖöŞşÜü]+|$))/g, '$1')

document.write(result);
```

Comment: Cool pattern .. +1

Comment: Thanks works, but not works for turkish characters, it needs to be encoded

Answer (score 5):

If regex is not mandatory :), then try

```js
    var string='Girne Street No:1/2 Girne Girne KKTC KKTC';
    string = string.split(" ").filter(function(value,index,arr){ return value != arr[index+1];}).join(" ");
    document.body.innerHTML += string;
```

Comment: I wonder ... Why this solution didn't earn upvote !!! +1. I believe a regex solution should be the last option.

Comment: @Shafizadeh thanks, but it is a bit slower than georg http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split-filter-join-2, but works though :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this?

```
var str='Girne Street No:1/2 Girne Girne KKTC KKTC';
var result = str.replace(/\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/g,'$1');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks works, but not works for turkish characters, it needs to be encoded

Comment: You can replace \w to turkish alphabet:
var str='İyiyim, teşekkür teşekkür ederim!';
var result = str.replace(/\b([a,b,c,ç,d,e,f,g,ğ,h,i,ı,j,k,l,m,n,o,ö,p,r,s,ş,t,u,ü,v,y,z]+)\s+\1\b/g,'$1');
console.log(result);

\w means [A-z], latin symbols