# Java program to remove consecutive duplicate characters from string

Tags: java

The input string is 'aabbbcabcaa' and the output string should be 'cabc'.

I tried below code but it is not giving me required output:

```
public class removeConsecativeDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "aabbbcabcaa";
        System.out.println(removeConsecativeDuplicat(input));
    }

    public static String removeConsecativeDuplicat(String input) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 2; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(i - 1) & input.charAt(i - 1) != input.charAt(i - 2)) {
                result.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use a separate local variable to store past characters.

Comment: In Java, the first character in a String is at position 0 rather than position 1.

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```java
"aabbbcabcaa".replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "")
```

Inspired by the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636593/remove-consecutive-duplicate-characters-in-a-string-javascript).

Also refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 0):

Let's look what will happen for the input string "aab".
the for loop will run once with i = 2
the condition with the correct values will be `'b' != 'a' & 'a' != 'a'` which evaluates to `false` and so nothing will be appended to result.
If you take the input string "abc" instead, the condition will be true but you skipped the first 2 characters so the output will only be "c".

Instead of comparing the characters with each other, your approach here should be to count how many consecutive characters there are and add them to the result string, if there is only one.

```java
char lastchar = input.charAt(0); //check beforehand that the string isn't empty
int count = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++) {
   if (input.charAt(i) == lastchar) {
      count += 1;
   } else {
        if (count == 1) {
            result.append(lastchar);
        }
        count = 0;
        lastchar = input.charAt(i);
    }
}
if (count == 1) {
    result.append(lastchar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat problem; most of the "remove duplicates" exercises intend that a single character from each set of duplicates is left behind, but in this case the problem is harder -- if the character is duplicated, *completely* remove it.  You're on the right track but your logic isn't quite right.  You want to take each character in turn, look backwards one and forwards one, if either are the same character then skip it. otherwise print:

```
public class removeConsecativeDuplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "aabbbcabcaa";
        System.out.println(removeConsecutives(input));
    }

    private static boolean isSame(String input,int idx1,int idx2) {
        if (idx1 < 0 || idx2 >= input.length()) return false; // catch first and last characters
        return input.charAt(idx1) == input.charAt(idx2);
    }
    
    public static String removeConsecutives(String input) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (isSame(input, i, i+1)) { continue; }
            if (isSame(input, i-1, i)) { continue; }
            result = result.append(input.charAt(i));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check again to your IDE and try this solution:

```java
public class removeConsecativeDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "aabbbcabcaa";
        System.out.println(removeConsecativeDuplicates(input));
    }

    public static String removeConsecativeDuplicates(String input) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 2; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(i - 1) & input.charAt(i - 1) != input.charAt(i - 2)) {
                result.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the user check in their IDE?  Is this a new solution or a restatement?